# Why does the int keyword have an effect on the variable value when changing a variable

Tags: c

If I do something like this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
a = a + b;
```

a gives 3 in this instance, however if I do something like this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int a = a + b
```

a gives a very large number (1827585825)

Can anyone explain why this occurs?

Comment: It shouldn't give *any* number, because it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Redefinition of variable as you attempted is not allowed in C, and fails to compile. However, a slightly modified version of your code does compile:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    {
      int a = a + b;
      // use a
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`int a = a + b` is valid, but doesn't mean what you think it does. The `a` in `a + b` refers to the inner and as-yet uninitialized variable `a`, and not to the outer `a`. Using it in an expression is undefined behavior and results in garbage output.

Comment: *`However, a slightly modified version of your code does compile:`* It does not for me: https://godbolt.org/z/j9cc1fMdT

Comment: @0___________ It does when placed [inside a function](https://godbolt.org/z/KEEfzcP1P). I've now amended the answer to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid and it will not compile at all.

The second `a` definition has to be in a different scope like in the example below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1;
int b = 2;

int main(void)
{
    int a = a + b;  //declares new a variable which has undetermined value
}
```

The second definition of `a` hides the global one and newly defined `int` variable will not be initialized. You take this not initialized variable (having undetermined value) and add another value to it. The result will also undetermined. It is Undefined Behaviour.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm